# Convert List<BufferedImage> to Image

Tags: java, image, user-interface, bufferedimage

I have the following .ico image, read using image4j library:

```
List<BufferedImage> BI = ICODecoder.read("aImage.ico");
```

Next I want to set this image as a frame icon:

```
myFrame.setIconImage((Image)BI);
```

***Error: java.lang.ClassCastException***

I need to convert the type List<\BufferedImage> to the type Image. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Zavior I'd say not, you can pass a `BufferedImage` to any method that accepts `Image` as `BufferedImage` extends `Image`, but a `List` of `BufferedImage`s is in no way compatible for with `Image`...

Comment: This is clearly *not* a duplicate of the question that so far, 4 inattentive users have voted to close this question for... Reviewers, *please* pay attention when reviewing close votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using...

```
myFrame.setIconImage(BI.get(0));
```

`List` is a list of stuff (or technically `Object`s, in your case, `BufferedImage`s), where as `setIconImage` expects just one...

Alternatively, you could take advantage of of `JFrame`'s capability of providing multiple different images at different resolutions by using...

```
myFrame.setIconImages(BI);
```

Which is probably what you were after in the first place...

Comment: `stuff` - is that a technical word then?

Comment: @user2310289 I didn't want to get to committed to a single concept ;)

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
 List<BufferedImage> BI = ICODecoder.read("aImage.ico");
```

you are loading into a `List`

so when you try to do `myFrame.setIconImage((Image)BI);` you will not be able to convert a list into an image.

try a `.get(0)` on the list to return the Image.