# Jdialog box Title bar icon change

Tags: java, css, swing, swingx

I need to change the Jdialog box title bar icon. By default it uses a java coffee image.

I have searched in internet and used many codes

```
1. Image im = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/org/qmon/generate/Images/JDialog -2.ico");
        dialog.setIconImage(im);

2. Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();
        Image img = kit.getImage ("/org/qmon/generate/Images/Create File Tag-16x16.png");

        dialog.setIconImage(img);
```

nothing works properly.. Kindly help me.. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firtsly, `ico` is not a support image format for Java.

The likely reason you're having issues with the second approach is that `getImage` is expecting a file reference and the image you seem to referencing looks like it's embedded (stored within your application)

Try using something more like...

```
Image img = kit.getImage (getClass().getResource("/org/qmon/generate/Images/Create File Tag-16x16.png"));
```

Instead.

Personally, I prefer `ImageIO.read` as it throws a `IOException` when something goes wrong...

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/org/qmon/generate/Images/Create File Tag-16x16.png"));
```

But that's me...

You should also consider taking a look at [Convert List<BufferedImage> to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061361/convert-listbufferedimage-to-image/22061426#22061426) which demonstrates the use of `ico` file (from a 3rd party API) and [`setIconImages`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages(java.util.List)) method

Comment: Thanks buddy this code worsk  `Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/org/qmon/generate/Images/Create File Tag-16x16.png"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL(
        "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f1d58f7932b6ae8027c4e1d84f440ffe?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"));
    dialog.setIconImage( image );
    dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Another way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in my application and working fine

```
    java.net.URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("res/java.png");
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jep, "UroSync",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve what *MadProgrammer* has said, I met the problem and I solved it instantiating a JDialog but using the static class `Toolkit` method `getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Image img)`.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(MyMainClass.class.getResource("/myIcon.png")));
```

To do that you need to add before the image into the build path of the Project.